wayland screenshot tool with annotations
Which tool to use to take screenshots of
areas selected by mouse on wayland, and
annotate afterwards?
None of tools that I was using works with 24.04

not tried it personally on 24.04 (only running on live USB currently) but you might wish to to try shutter on Wayland and if it works let me know and I'll post as an answer. Thanks

Thanks @graham eventually it worked, but version 0.99.2-5 which was in zip file as .deb, it offers selection screenshot only if called from main window's file menu... I'll try to dig more to bind it to some shortcut...

eventually replaced print screen by adding new custom shortcut "shutter area" via custom shortcuts command is shutter -s

what were the issues and is it worth posting as an answer? I think the last update was Dec '23 and was pre 24.04 of course.

The other version shutter-on-wayland_0.99.4-5_all.deb crashes and asks for gnome-web-photo, but 099.2-5 works...

perhaps you'd like to post your own answer on those findings including where to find 099.2-55 and how to install it. You can then accept your own answer after a day or so by clicking on the grey tick alongside your answer and I'll be happy to upvote it just for good measure. Shutter is a useful tool and it deserves mention here.
